# How to disable logging after migration to Selenium 4

Tags: java, selenium, logging

couple days ago I've updated Selenium libraries to the newest 4.1.4. Earlier I used an old version like 3.141.59 and when I executed TestNG tests, then I got only logs from ITestListener, Reporter  and from TestNG.

Now when I execute tests I got a bunch of logs I don't need. I have set nothing related to the logs in my code.
How can I disable that logs?

It looks like:

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 7.4.0
08:58:45.409 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.logging.InternalLoggerFactory - Using SLF4J as the default logging framework
08:58:45.416 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.ResourceLeakDetector - -Dio.netty.leakDetection.level: simple
08:58:45.416 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.ResourceLeakDetector - -Dio.netty.leakDetection.targetRecords: 4
08:58:45.420 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.ResourceLeakDetectorFactory - Loaded default ResourceLeakDetector: io.netty.util.ResourceLeakDetector@352ff4da
08:58:45.442 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - -Dio.netty.noUnsafe: false
08:58:45.442 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - Java version: 15
08:58:45.443 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - sun.misc.Unsafe.theUnsafe: available
08:58:45.444 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - sun.misc.Unsafe.copyMemory: available
08:58:45.444 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - java.nio.Buffer.address: available
08:58:45.445 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - direct buffer constructor: unavailable: Reflective setAccessible(true) disabled
08:58:45.446 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - java.nio.Bits.unaligned: available, true
```

Comment: Are you using `spring` or `spring-boot` for executing application & tests?

Comment: I execute tests form TestNG.xml file - Run as TestNG Suite. I don't use spring.

Comment: Does this help https://ivanderevianko.com/2020/04/disable-logging-in-selenium-chromedriver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using logback for logging purpose, then create `logback.xml` configuration file under `src/main/resources` as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <property name="LOGS" value="./logs" />
    <appender name="Console" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <pattern>
            %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm.ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
            </pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="Console" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

So basically setting the root level as "info" will solve the issue. Selenium 4 by default prints with root level as "debug".